# Securesocial and playframework - how do i install?

Tags: java, playframework, securesocial

This is silly - how do i install secruesocial for playframework 2.5?

This page - https://playframework.com/modules/securesocial-0.2.4/home - is entirely unhelpful.

I don't know what "play deps" means, where to run it from, or where the play.exe file even is. I'm using "activator start" to start my play server... is play deps something else?

I also don't know what/where the dependencies.yml file is, or how i'm meant to add an entry to it!

Comment: You should look into [Silhouette](https://github.com/mohiva/play-silhouette). SecureSocial does not support the latest play versions as far as I know

Comment: @nmat where did you hear about it from (i'll look into it, just wanting to know where the "latest" play stuff is)

Comment: @nmat also - ARGH - i'm developing in java. is there a java version of silhouette?

Comment: Sorry, it's scala only. Here's a list:https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ModuleDirectory